# How to add a subject in sendmail()

Tags: python, odoo

//The below code is my python file.
//I want to add a subject to this. while i'm adding subject parameter to sendmail().
//It shows error in odoo.
//How could i do this!!!

```
Code:

 def sendotp(self):
          if self.mail:
                mail = self.mail
                otp = ''.join(str(random.randint(0,9))for i in range 
                server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                server.starttls()
                server.login(<mymail>,password)
                msg = 'Hi, your OTP is ,' +str(otp)
                server.sendmail('priyaraji.c24@gmail.com',mail,msg)
                server.quit()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example shows how to add From and To header. Subject is another header you could add in the same manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the smtp message using `MIMEText` parts

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def sendotp(self):
      if self.mail:
            mail = self.mail
            otp = ''.join(str(random.randint(0,9))for i in range 
            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
            server.starttls()
            server.login(<mymail>,password)

            # MIMEText mail message
            msg = MIMEText('Hi, your OTP is ,' + str(otp))
            msg['Subject'] = 'Test mail'
            msg['From'] = 'priyaraji.c24@gmail.com'
            msg['To'] = mail

            server.sendmail('priyaraji.c24@gmail.com',mail,msg.as_string())
            server.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks@chrisbyte...but i'm using smtp

Comment: My answer is smtp...I updated my post to include your settings. It only adds the `MIMEText` mail object

Answer (score 0):

Sending email in odoo is pretty simple

```
mail_values = {
    'subject': subject,
    'body_html': body_html,
    'email_to': self.send_email_to,
    'email_from': email_from,
    'state': 'outgoing'
}
self.env['mail.mail'].sudo().create(mail_values).send()
```

Comment: It does not work for me sir@Muhammad yusuf

Answer (score 0):

//This statement worked for me.

SUBJECT = "Subject"
TEXT = "Message body"

message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(SUBJECT, TEXT)